# Unity - 2D - проблема с воспроизведением звука

Tags: unity3d, аудио

Если поставить PlayOnAwake, то один раз звук проиграет. Через код и инспектор уже пробовал разными способами воспроизвести звук. Не работает. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int _damage;

    private AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioClip impact;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.TryGetComponent(out Player player))
        {
            player.ApplyDamage(_damage);

            if (!audioSource.isPlaying)
            {
                audioSource.PlayOneShot(impact, 0.7F);
                Debug.Log("All ok");
            }
        }
        Die();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
    private void Die()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Консоль, которая показывает, что код выполняется (Debug.log выполнился):
[image: Консоль]

Сам префаб:
[image: Префаб с настройками]

Answer (score 0):

Понял.

gameObject.SetActive(false); - Можно сказать деактивирует объет и звук вместе с ним.

Как решение - повесить звук на другой объект, который не будет деактивироваться. А так код правильный.

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь деактивировать не объект, а компоненты:

```
this.enabled = false;
GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
```

`Update`, `FixedUpdate`, `OnEnable`, `OnCollision...` и другие методы юнити перестанут исполняться.